# How to write a program that takes the standard deviation of a list of numbers by defining a function?

Tags: python, list, function, math, standard-deviation

This is a homework assignment that asks to define a function stddev(xs) that calculates the standard deviation of a list of numbers. (Standard deviation is found by taking the square root of the sum of the mean subtracted from each number in the list divided by the total number of terms.) I wrote a separate function which calculates the mean, and I verified that it works, however I am having trouble with the standard deviation function as I'm just having it return 0.0.

Side note: The only built-in list function I am allowed to use on this assignment is length. (i.e. I am not allowed to use append, remove, etc.)

Here is my code:

```
import math
def mean(xs):
    total = 0
    for i in range (0, len(xs)):
        total += xs[i]
    mean = total / len(xs)
    return mean

def stddev(xs):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    average = mean(xs)
    for i in range (0, len(xs)):
        sum = sum + (xs[i] - average)
        count += 1
    sd = math.sqrt (sum/count)
    return sd
list = [15, 10, 30, 50, 40]
print (stddev(list))
```

I would like to know why it is returning 0.0 instead of the standard deviation like I wanted it to.

Comment: Start [doing some debugging first](/help/how-to-ask): put a print for sum and count inside your `for` loop: what do you see happening? What does that tell you about the maths you implemented? (hint: if you have a list of `n` numbers, with some average `a`, the sum of all the numbers in the list is by definition equal to `n` times `a`)

Comment: I strongly advise you never to name a variable `sum`. In python, `sum` is the name of a builtin function, just like `len` or `range`. In fact, for your `mean` function, you could have just written: `def mean(xs): return sum(xs) / len(xs)`

Comment: Also I strongly advise you never to name a variable `list`. Shadowing the names of builtins like this leads to weird consequences. Here is the list of builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

### The main mistake

You forgot to take the absolute value. The variance and standard deviation are not a sum of differences, but rather, a sum of **distances**, or **absolute differences**.

Replace the following line:

```py
sum = sum + (xs[i] - average)
```

with:

```py
sum = sum + abs(xs[i] - average)
```

### Other comments

#### Shadowing builtins

I strongly advise you never to name a variable `sum` or `list`. These two names are names of builtin functions in python, just like `len` or `range`. Shadowing the names of builtins is heavily discouraged and can lead to unintended consequences.

Here is the full list of builtin names to avoid in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

#### For-loop: iterate on the elements, not the indices

When writing a for-loop to iterate on the elements of a list, it is recommended to iterate directly on the elements of the list, rather than on the indices.

For instance, instead of:

```py
total = 0
for i in range(len(xs)):
    total += xs[i]
```

You can just write:

```py
total = 0
for x in xs:
    total += x
```

This is easier to read, in my opinion. And less prone to off-by-one errors that can arise when choosing the bounds for the indices.

#### Using builtin `sum` to calculate a sum

Using builtin function `sum`, you can rewrite your two functions in a more compact and easy-to-read way:

```py
from math import sqrt

def mean(xs):
    return sum(xs) / len(xs)

def stddev(xs):
    m = mean(xs)
    var = sum(abs(x - m) for x in xs) / len(xs)
    return sqrt(var)
```